# GP Regression Model Predicting very similar numbers for all test inputs

Tags: python, regression, gaussian, gpy, gpyopt

I'm using **doc2vec embeddings** of amino acid sequences to try and predict kinetic rate.

I've tried both standardising and not standardising my input vectors (X) but unless I standardise my output variable (kinetic rates), my GP model predicts very similar numbers for all the test inputs **(between 4.87 and 4.9)**?

Are you supposed to standardise your output values or is there something wrong with my model?

I'm using the **GPy** package in Python.

This is my code:

```
#GP Regression for word vectors
def Gp_regression(Xtrain, Ytrain, Xtest, Ytest):

    kernel = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim = 64, variance = 1, lengthscale =    1)
    m = GPy.models.GPRegression(Xtrain, Ytrain, kernel=kernel,    noise_var=1e-10)
    m.optimize_restarts(num_restarts = 10)

    Xtest = np.ndarray(shape=(1,64))
    mean = m.predict(Xtest)

return mean
```

Comment: wow, that's one incredibly domain specific question, with very few details to help non-stats people!  including some of the model and data would help, but I expect they are both large and difficult to post.  there's so much you've left out of the question that it's difficult to say much

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure how much detail to give, I've never posted on here before haha. I have vectors of dimension 64 and I'm trying to predict the log kinetic rates using GP regression that correspond to each vector (between 3.06 and 7.18). If I standardise the log kinetic rates, my model predicts pretty well but if I dont standardise them it predicts pretty much the same value for all the input vectors. I haven't done much stats for a long time so I'm pretty new to whole idea of GP Regression so I'm not entirely sure what could lead to the model predicting the same values.

Comment: why are you replacing the `Xtest` variable with an uninitialized `ndarray`?

Comment: Thank you! I definitely shouldn't be doing that! I'm ending up giving the model the same vector over and over which is why the predicted values are all the same.

Comment: So I changed that so it's definitely taking different vectors but the issue is still the same. When I print my model the objective value is positive (Objective: 87.35531276527225). Any example I've seen online has a negative value for objective?

Comment: when you say "Objective" do you mean the log-likelihood? whether it's positive or negative shouldn't matter and will depend on the data and model.  [GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf) used to be the standard text on this but it might be a bit theoretical for your tastes, there are probably more applied ones in your area